# The Angular way to use a function result in a template?

Tags: angularjs

I'm still new to angular and figuring it out as I go with a few examples. What I'm trying to do now is find a proper way to format something. I have a Job object that looks like this:

```
$scope.Job = {
  "JobUID": 100,
  "FirstName": "Corey",
  "LastName": "Ogburn"
}
```

And on my page, I want to display it something like this:

```
<p>Patient Name: {{ Job.LastName + ', ' + Job.FirstName }}</p>
```

Although this works, I'm hoping there's a way to call a function that prepares the name. For example having a `GetFullName()` function on my Job object and then having a template similar to:

```
<p>Patient Name: {{ Job.GetFullName() }}</p>
```

This doesn't seem to work. I've read up on custom filters, but I'm not sure if that's the *right* way to do it. I think I'd have to pass in the entire Job and I'm inclined to find another way to do it before trying that.

How can I use a function to prepare data to be used in a template?

Comment: can you post the `GetFullName` function because that should work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are "objects" in angular that can help you with the task you mentioned those are "**Services**" or "**Factories**". They are not more than Javascript classes(objects) that you can later inject in your controller not much different than what you do with the `$scope`.

But in order to simplify the process you can implement a class either directly in your controller or outside of it, doing something like this:

```
function Job() {

  this.JobUID = 100;
  this.FirstName = "Corey";
  this.LastName= "Ogburn";
 }

Job.prototype.GetFullName = function(){
  return this.LastName + ',' + this.FirstName;
}

$scope.Job = new Job();
```

Then on your **HTML** code:

```
<p>Patient Name: {{ Job.GetFullName() }}</p>
```

Comment: I definitely prefer this to cluttering up $scope because I'm going to have a lot going on and I'd like to keep things properly modular.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a function, it should work:

```
<p>Patient Name: {{ GetFullName(Job) }}</p>
```

**JS (controller):**

```
$scope.GetFullName = function(job) {

    return job.LastName+ ', ' + job.FirstName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/3205/)

```
$scope.Job = {
   "JobUID": 100,
   "FirstName": "Corey",
   "LastName": "Ogburn"
}

$scope.fullname = function() {
    return $scope.Job.LastName + ", " + $scope.Job.FirstName;
}
```

Markup:

```
<p>Patient Name: {{ fullname() }}</p>
```